# How can I see each frame of a mpeg transport stream under windows?

Tags: file-formats, software-recommendation, mpeg

I am looking for a tool, preferably free, that will allow me to see and save each frame from MPEG-2 Transport Stream (video/mp2t).

Comment: Anything missing?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [MPEG Streamclip for Windows](http://www.squared5.com/svideo/mpeg-streamclip-win.html). It's a very usefull converter. It's free. You can step frame-by-frame thought your TS-Streams, and you can export frames.